# Passing object in routing.yml

Tags: entities, 8, routes

I have an entity and when I try to pass the whole entity object, only the name is passed through the routing.

Here is the relevant code in routing.yml:

```
mymodule.myentity_info:
  path: '/admin/config/mymodule/myentity/{myentity}/info'
  defaults:
    _content: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::info'
    _title: 'Myentity Info'
  options:
    parameters:
      myentity:
      type: entity:myentity
  requirements:
    _entity_create_access: 'mymodule_myentity'
```

After clicking the link, I get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

I've added an issue regarding this to my sandbox project: https://www.drupal.org/node/2301021

Comment: Couldn't be as simple as `type` not being indented correctly under the parameters?

Comment: @Clive: Nope. It still throws he same error. I tried doing a `print_r($myentity)`. It just displays the name of that entity I added in string. Is there any example which I could refer to maybe?

Comment: @Clive`
I'm disturbed that the YAML `options:` and `parameters:` keys doesn't appear anywhere in google search results, or like https://www.drupal.org/node/2192175 or a change record i can find :(

Comment: @Clive: Yes. I took that from https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643. Basically, I'm trying to output an entity's info. The `info($myentity)` function should take the argument as the Entity object, but all it does is take just the name.

Comment: Maybe you need a custom parameter converter for your entity type? I can't look right now but search around the change records and the new routing docs for parameter upcasting. I'm not sure if you're automagically provided one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is now called upcasting, the handbook page is https://www.drupal.org/node/2122223

I do not think `options` is necessarily for entity upcasting. For example, check the `node.type_edit` in `core/modules/node/node.routing.yml` for a routing definition not using any `options` (or `user.admin_permission` in user).

As with your previous question, I wonder whether your entity class properly defines its storage controller? If you have a debugger, the parameter conversion happens in `core/lib/Drupal/Core/ParamConverter/EntityConverter.php`

Comment: I followed your advice, and still was unable to debug it. You could view the issue that I've added to my sandbox project. https://www.drupal.org/node/2301021

Comment: Seems like the function name `info` was posing problems, maybe having conflicts. Changing the function name resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Which function name have you changed...? This sounds curious.

Comment: You may view my commit: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-prateeksachan-2275583/commit/?h=8.x-1.x&id=ccbad1b847002012848c01dd98b56e6db43f3070